# Delete records from table where date is older then value found in related table

Tags: sql-server

Given the following

```
Clients Table
--------------
Id int 
DaysToLive int
```

and

```
CallRecords Table
-----------------
ClientId int
Reported bit
ReportedTime DateTime2
```

I'm trying to do delete all records in the `CallRecords table`, that has a `ReportTime` older than the `DaysToLive` column in the `Clients Table`

The following is running in a background service (client by client), however i'm  trying to convert it to raw sql to use in a sql agent scheduled job

```
Delete from CallRecords where ClientId = {0} and Reported = 1 and ReportedTime < GETDATE() - {1}
```

However i'm not sure how to structure this for all clients with a `join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear about the date condition,but

Try like this:

```
DELETE cr
FROM CallRecords cr
INNER JOIN Clients c
  ON c.Id =cr.ClientId
Where cr.Reported = 1 AND <the date condition>.
```